# Build Failing when Publishing to SmarterASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, hosting, visual-studio-2019

I was able to publish my web app a while ago, and I'm coming back to it now. I've made some changes, not totally sure what all together now, and it just keeps failing. It gives me this in the log file:

5/4/2020 5:34:53 PM
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Exception: Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.WebTools.Publish.PublishService.VsWebProjectPublish.<>c__DisplayClass43_0.b__3()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Publish.Framework.ViewModel.ProfileSelectorViewModel.d__213.MoveNext()
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Exception: Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.<---

System.Exception: Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.

===================

And in the output window, it just says it failed trying to delete a file. I've tried publishing with deleting everything and without, both fail the same way.

I can build locally just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SmarterASP.net often has issue with certificate and you have to reaccept it.

> Note:If you get certificate error with publish,please add below code
>   to your PublishProfiles.
>
> `<AllowUntrustedCertificate>True</AllowUntrustedCertificate>`

- SmarterASP.net [Knowledge base reference](https://www.smarterasp.net/support/kb/a1779/how-to-publish-asp_net-core-web-application-via-visual-studio-2015.aspx?KBSearchID=706302)

Comment: I'm not even using .net core but it fixed it. Thanks!